# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for + when using sum

Tags: python, sum, addition

I have a class with my own implementation of `__add__`:

```
class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y', 'z'])):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)
```

Addition works as expected:

```
l = [Point(0,0,0), Point(0,1,2)]
s = l[0]
for a in l[1:]:
    s = s + a
```

But when I use builtin `sum` I'm getting an error:

```
s = sum(l)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Point'

What's wrong in my code? Doesn't `sum` use `__add__`? What more should I override?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "__radd__" instead of "__add__"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sum` function initializes its result variable with the integer value 0:

```
sum(iterable[, start]) -> value

    Return the sum of an iterable of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
    of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).
```

So inside of sum, the addition `0 + Point(0,0,0)` is performed, which your class doesn't support.

To get around this, pass a suitable value for `start`:

```
s = sum(l, Point(0,0,0))
```

Comment: Is that from the official docs? it's quite misleading to say the least.

Comment: @DeepSpace That excerpt is from `help(sum)`, not sure if it's the same as the docs.

Comment: That's seems like a working workaround; do you know if there's a way to encode _within the Point class_ that the neutral element of addition is Point(0,0,0)?

Comment: @sygi Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: @sygi you could try defining addition (and r-addition) for the case where `isinstance(other, int) and other == 0` as addition of Point(0, 0, 0)? Like this:
 (... with semicolons since apparently I can't do multiline in here)
`    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z);
        elif isinstance(other, int) and other == 0:
            return self # === self + Point(0, 0, 0);
        else:
            return NotImplemented;
`

Answer (score 2):

You could also override the `__radd__()` function:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return Point(self.x + other, self.y + other, self.z + other)
```

Note that this must be done *additionally* to overriding `__add__()`

Comment: I did that, although I prefer `__radd__ = __add__` :)

Comment: Nb: for it to work, you also need to implement adding `Point` to `int` (0).

Comment: I tested the version in the answer and it worked without any additions. There is a tiny difference in the code, namely you add `other` and not `other.{x,y,z}`

Comment: Yes, but it changes behavior in a wrong way -- you're adding `Point`s to each coordinates' `int`s retulting in a Point of Points of ints: `P(x=P(x=3, y=4), y=P(x=4, y=5))`